# Is javac an oracle java compiler?

Tags: java, ubuntu

I compile my java code using javac. But I am not sure which compiler it is.

`man javac` says it is gcj-4.6, which seems provided by GNU. I have OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime installed.

But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_compiler) says javac is from Oracle.

> Major Java compilers[edit] As of 2012, the following are major Java
>   compilers:[citation needed]
>
> - The Java Programming Language Compiler (javac), included in the Java Development Kit from Oracle Corporation, open-sourced since 13
>     November 2006.
> - GNU Compiler for Java (GCJ), a part of the GNU Compiler Collection, which compiles C, Fortran, Pascal and other programming languages
>     besides Java. It can also generate native code using the back-end of
>     GCC.
> - Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ), an open source incremental compiler used by the Eclipse project.

I don't know how to check if I have Oracle's installed.

I am confused. Thanks.

Comment: All of them have name `javac`

Comment: there are many java compiler openjdk, sun java, oracle java, etc. It is what makes java portable as in it can run on any java virtual machine.

Comment: @jgr208: what makes it portable is the runtime, not the compiler.

Comment: @njzk2 I know that. I meant not having openjdk compiled code only run on an openjdk jvm and oracle on oracle jvm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: oracle acquired sun microsystems, anyone can implement java spec, oracle is obviously first one to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javac` is just the name (or alias) of the program doing the compilation.

Just like `cc` is a common alias to the C compiler (whether it be `clang`, `gcc`, etc), `javac` is just the name standardized around by implementations (GNU or Oracle).

Answer (score 2):

Javac is just the command used to run the compiler. You can use openjdk, sun or oracle java and they all use the `javac` command.

To tell which version you are using do the following

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [pick it yourself](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java#Choosing_the_default_Java_to_use)! Simply run `sudo update-alternatives --config java`.